# What is the max level in SteamWorld Dig 2?

Tags: steamworld-dig-2

In SteamWorld Dog 2, leveling up by defeating enemies will unlock new upgrade options at the workbench and increase the sell bonus when exchanging materials.

What is the maximum possible level in SteamWorld Dig 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max level is 20. Max cogs as far as I'm aware is 84, you will not be able to earn enough to have all mods equipped. And then there are 42 relics.

The sell bonus for reaching level 20 is 95%. (5% for each level past 1)

Comment: I don't remember, but you won't be able to earn enough money in the world to buy everything. Though your could grind gems if you equip a certain mod that causes enemies to drop em.

Comment: There are 43 relics. You get one extra for completing *The Cave of Trials*.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I haven't completed, it got hard real fast. I'm just going by what is displayed on the save. 42/42. I never really knew what the reward was for completing that, other than 100% which I always try for.